# KendoUI Inline Edit Numeric Text Box with other culture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, globalization, culture

I am using Kendo Grid (version 2014.1.318) with inline editing on "de-DE" culture. So the numbers should  use a comma(,) as the decimal separator, eg: 79,5.

The Numeric Text Box in the grid is displaying the expected format when in "Edit" mode. No problem here. But when I click on "Update" button, it is sending "79.5" instead of "79,5" back to my server. My server is configured with the "de-DE" culture and the ModelBinder couldn't process numbers in that format and as a result, assigned ZERO to my variable.

Is this a known bug or am I missing something? Everything is fine when i use "en-US" culture or any culture that uses period(.) as its decimal separator.

Comment: Does this help? [Kendo globalization](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/globalization)

Comment: I've already used the same Culture on both server and client sides but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Did you include the kendo.culture.de-DE.min.js file:

Did you change the kendo culture:

```
kendo.culture("de-DE");
```

At last you can also try to change the culture in the numeric text box:

```
@Html.Kendo().NumericTextBox().Culture("de-DE")
```

Comment: As I have already mentioned `The Numeric Text Box in the grid is displaying the expected format when in "Edit" mode. No problem here.`, of course I have already done those you mentioned. Otherwise I wouldn't be saying `is displaying the expected format`.

Answer (score 0):

We are having the same problem for a year now. It seems it's on low priority for Telerik to solve this or we missed the solution.

This is how we solved it:

Pass this function to the data function of grid create and update like here:

```
.Update(update => update.Action("Update", "Gradings").Type(HttpVerbs.Put).Data("convertDecimals")))

function convertDecimals(data) {
  for (var property in data) {
    var value = data[property];
    if (typeof value === "number") {
      // if the number is integer
      if (value % 1 == 0) {
        data[property] = value.toString();
      }
      else {
        data[property] = kendo.toString(value, "n");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and this on edit:

```
.Events(events => events.Edit("replaceDecimalSign"))

function replaceDecimalSign(data) {
  var value = $(data).val();
  var converted = value.toString().replace('.', ',');
  $(data).val(converted);
}
```

Also you need the correct culture settings like alreay answered by MohQut.

```
kendo.culture("de-DE");
```